# Hamburger for Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, hamburger-menu

I have a problem, so this is when I try to follow a link through a hamburger using `routerLink` the hamburger should close but it won't close.

I wrote `CSS` and it works as it should.
The hamburger lets me down even if I insert it `href`
It goes to the main page and not to `/about`

If you have any input for this task, please advise.

My code:

```js
menuVisible = false;

function toggleMenu() {
  this.menuVisible = !this.menuVisible;
}
```

```css
label .menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #293332;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #FFF, 0 0 0 0 #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #69D2e7;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

label .hamburger:after,
label .hamburger:before {
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
}

label .hamburger:before {
  top: -10px;
}

label .hamburger:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

label input {
  display: none;
}

label input:checked+.menu {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 60vw #000007, 0 0 0 60vh #FFF;
  border-radius: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

label input:checked+.menu .hamburger {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

label input:checked+.menu .hamburger:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

label input:checked+.menu .hamburger:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
}

label input:checked+.menu+ul {
  opacity: 1;
}

label ul {
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: Copperplate, serif;
  color: red;
  font-weight: Italic;
  background-color: #D4AC0D;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: green;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
  color: #380707;
  font-size: 42px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  background-color: #D4AC0D;
}

.bg-dark {
  background-color: #D4AC0D!important
}

.navbar-toggler {
  background-color: brown;
}

.nav-item:hover>.nav-link {
  font-family: Copperplate, serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: red !important;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  font-family: Copperplate, serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.bg-dark {
  background-color: aqua;
}


/*
.nav-link > a:hover {
  font-family: Copperplate , serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: green;
}
*/

.navbar-toggler {
  color: white !important;
}

.navbar.collapse {
  display: none;
}

.navbar.show {
  background: white !important;
}

.collapse {}
```

```html
<div class="" mouseover="toggleMenu()" mouseout="toggleMenu()">
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="menu"> 
  <span class="hamburger"></span> 
  </span>



  <ul>
    <li> <a class="u-btn u-button-style u-block-control u-block-adf6-34" routerLink="/about">Home</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="u-btn u-button-style u-block-control u-block-adf6-34" href="/about">About</a> </li>
    <a class="" href="http://localhost:4200/#/about">Conta</a>
  </ul>

</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have the line:
   `<a class="" href="http://localhost:4200/#/about">Conta</a>`
   within the `ul`.
2. `http://localhost:4200/#/about`
   is the root page (`http://localhost:4200/`)
   after the # is the fragment identifier.
   It is not the same as `/about` or `http://localhost:4200/about` (unless you have a bespoke configured web-server)